# Converting row names into one columns in R and export to txt file

Tags: r

I have multiple same names in a row with different dates and values corresponding to it. I want to consolidate that rows and make columns with the date and its value. any idea how to do it in R? (I m learing R)

```
ID  Date    Value
62  17/03/2008  1
62  29/09/2008  9
62  01/01/2009  0
66  01/04/2009  6
66  29/06/2009  3
66  30/09/2009  5
75  01/01/2010  6
75  01/04/2010  0
91  01/07/2010  8
91  28/09/2010  0
```

I want to convert it like below

```
 62        62   66        66    75         75
17/03/2008  1   01/04/2009  6   01/01/2010  6
29/09/2008  9   29/06/2009  3   01/04/2010  0
01/01/2009  0   30/09/2009  5
```

Once this is done, I want to write the output files for groups(e.g. 62, 66, 75) in txt format with the name of txt file as group names with prefix 'a'(e.g. 62a.txt, 66a.txt, 75a.txt). I have very long dataset hence some sort of looping has to be done.

Comment: Can you format your question to be more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of output do you want? Do you want to `split` your data according to ID? That would return a list with an entry for each ID. 
Here's the `data.frame`, for a reproducible example. Similarly, you should also provide the structure of the desired output.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(62L, 62L, 62L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 75L, 75L, 
      91L, 91L), Date = structure(c(6L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 
      5L, 7L), .Label = c("01/01/2009", "01/01/2010", "01/04/2009", 
      "01/04/2010", "01/07/2010", "17/03/2008", "28/09/2010", "29/06/2009", 
      "29/09/2008", "30/09/2009"), class = "factor"), Value = c(1L, 
      9L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 8L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", 
      "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

This is what I think you want to do:

```
split(df, df[,"ID"])
split(df[,c("Date", "Value")], df[,"ID"])
```

Comment: Wow the split function works. I have some more operations to perform which i have updated in my question. see if you can help. Thanks